# Continuous and holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a closed unit disk, $U$ - open unit disc. Is there a function $f$ continuous on $D$ and holomorphic on $U$, such that $f(z)=z^2+\frac{2}{z}$ for all $z \in D \setminus U$.

It seems to me that here we need to apply the Riemann mapping theorem. But $f(z)$ not suitable. Maybe here is a negative answer?

Comment: What is $\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} z^2 + \frac{2}{z}\,dz$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: why this function is continuous on $D$ and holomorphic on $U$?

Comment: I neither said it is, nor that it isn't. Consider necessary and/or sufficient conditions for the existence of such an $f$. You know several such conditions that can answer the question. Finding one that does may take a couple of tries, but there aren't so many options that it's infeasible to check them.